# Can't use new disk space after vdi hd resize

Tags: virtualbox, hard-disk, disk-usage, gparted

I have a RHEL 7 vdi running on VirtualBox. Hard disk had a size of 8 Go and I wanted to resize it to 12 Go.
On host machine I successfully used VirtualBox's modifyhd utility. Then I ran GParted and extended the /dev/sda2 partition size so now I have :
[image: GParted view]

Unfortunately when I next reboot, df is still showing the old size and OS complaining about limited disk space, although all other commands seem to see the 12 Go :
[image: Result of df, lsblk & sfdisk commands]

Any ideas what I might have done wrong?

Comment: You also need to resize the volume group `vgresize <VG>`.

Comment: @eblock thanks. what do i need to install in order to use that command ? i am getting 'unknown command'

Comment: My bad, it should be `pvresize /dev/sdX`, of course.

Comment: @eblock Thanks, I did `pvresize /dev/sda2`. Unfortunately it seems to have no effect as `df` still shows the same result.

Comment: You also need to resize the logical volumes to fit the requirements, with pvresize you only resized the underlying device. Can you see the additional space in `vgs`? If so, you can now extend the LVs by running: `lvresize -L <SIZE>GB <VG_NAME>/<LV_NAME>`. After that, you'll also have to resize the filesystem, something like `resize2fs /dev/<VG>/<LV>` or `xfs_growfs ...`.

Comment: @eblock Ok, finally I made it! I sucessfully ran lvresize, then struggled a bit with resize2fs but eventually xfs_growfs did the trick. Thank you so much for your help.
Can you please post your comments as an answer so I can validate it? Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to resize the underlying partition:

```
pvresize /dev/sda2
```

After that your volume group should have access to the additional space. Now you need to resize the logical volumes:

```
lvresize -L <SIZE>GB <VG_NAME>/<LV_NAME>
xfs_growfs /dev/...
```

`xfs_growfs` is for XFS filesystem, of course. If you have a different FS, please use the respective command (e.g. `resize2fs`).

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a virtual box and allocate space manually.
2. Now you can see the vdi disk space by typing - `lsblk`.
3. Resize the existing space using gparted GUI
4. Check the free space - `df -h` and the logical volume space - `lvdisplay` and free space - `vgs`
5. Now use the command `lvextend -L+5G /dev/zabbix-vg/root` to resize the volume.
6. Use the command `xfs_growfs /dev/zabbix-vg/root` to increase the size.
7. Check the size with df -h.